# Top tag works but bottom doesnt. Writing code in codepen

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.inner{
  margin-left:400px;
  color:white;
  width:650px;
  height:450px;

  top:130px;
  position:fixed;
  padding-left:30px;
  padding-right:30px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:grey;
}

.outer {
  height:500px;
  width:1000px;
  top:100px; 
   bottom:0px;
  margin-left:260px;
  position:fixed;

  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
</div>
<div class="inner">
    <img />
    <h2>RK</h2>
    <h5>wtv@wtc</h5>
    <a>
      Github 
    </a>

    <p>blah blah blah </p>

    <br>

    <p> blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

In the `outer` class, no matter how much I change the bottom, it does not alter anything on the resulting webpage. I think this is to do with block and inline but I really want to get my concepts straight. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using fixed positions for both divs, this is why they are overlapped. When you maximize the width, the inner content starts to appear. What is actually the final output you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "problem" is that you can not use `top` and `bottom` properties at the same time when using `position:fixed`

you can "offset" the element either relavant to the bottom of the screen or from the top. If you remove the `top:100px`, then the div should be positioned all the way at the bottom of the screen. 
You can also use the `left` property and set it instead of current `margin-left` property.

you can read more about the different positioning options [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).